# Explain the concept of "accumulated momentum" for an electron

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I need someone to help me understand this equation:

$ \Delta p = qEt$ where $q$ is the charge, $E$ is the electric field and $t$ is in seconds. I thought that we were supposed to write momentum in this form: $p = mv$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field strength can be represented by the equation $$E=F/q$$ where $E$ is the electric field strength in N/C, $F$ is the force in Newtons, and $q$ is the charge in Coulombs.  If we take the equation that you provided: $$\Delta p=qEt$$, and substitute $F/q$ in for $E$, then $$\Delta p=q\frac Fq t$$ which simplifies to $$\Delta p=Ft$$
This looks shockingly similar to the impulse equation $$\Delta p=F\Delta t$$ So you can see that your equation simplifies to the classical expression for change in momentum.
Is it possible that you should have had a $\Delta t$ instead of just $t$ in your original equation?

Answer (score 1):

The equation simply says that the variation of momentum is equal to the force impulse. For a constant electric field $E$, we have that the force is $F=qE$. Then, we have
$$\Delta p=m\Delta v=mat=Ft=qEt$$